# Create PDF from PNG with ImageMagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, png

I have installed ImageMagick on my server for the purpose of converting a PNG image to PDF.  I came across this code:

```
convert image1.png image2.png image3.png output.pdf
```

Ref. http://www.wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=16778

I am not sure how to run this from PHP.  Also, I don't have image files, but rather, I have a stream like so:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Can someone tell me how to convert this image stream, `$im` to PDF using ImageMagick?  I've tried google'ing but I haven't found any examples.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$yourPngImage = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");
$im = new Imagick();

ob_start();
imagepng($yourPngImage);
$image_data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// Get image source data
$im->readimageblob($image_data);

$im->setImageFormat('pdf');

header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
echo $im;
```